# Moving all particle keys at once?

Tags: particles

I'm developing what's going to be a relatively complex keyed particle system. Problem is, in a regular keyed system, in most software where there's a timeline you can move one key and subsequent keys will move automatically along the timeline to accommodate. This is useful when I've got the framework of an animation but just want to make a part of the animation longer or shorter.

Even in Blender I know you can do this for regular animations. But is this possible for keyed particle systems, without having to change each and every keyed point by manually working out and changing the frame number?

It's easier to explain in a video
https://youtu.be/UOmkM93CnaI

Comment: What do you mean by "keyed" particle system? Is it that you animate some settings of the particle system, or do you refer to the keys that are generated when you "bake" the animation of the particles?

Comment: It's easier to explain in a video
https://youtu.be/UOmkM93CnaI

Comment: Ok I see what's going on (even if it would be better to have direct text explanation instead of a video). You are using the **"Keyed" physics type** for particle simulation, which is very different than **animation keys**. These physics "keys" has nothing to do with animation like you want to use in the timeline. I'm afraid you'll have to tweak every settings by hand, or do some python scripting to do that for you... Maybe someone here will help you with this kind of stuff, if you share your .blend file and reformulate your question a bit.

Comment: Thanks Polosson, I think you've possibly answered the question anyway! Thanks